# systemd make unit start and stop timer at the same time. However timer can start and stop without effecting unit

Tags: systemd

**System:**

- RHEL 7.4, systemd 219

**Units:**

- binary1.service
- binary2.service
- binary2.timer

**What I want:**

- When starting and stopping binary1.service, binary2.timer will be started and stopped.
- When bianry2.timer is started and stopped, binary2.timer will start and stop, but not affect the state of binary1.service.

**Problem:**

- I have tried using a variety of combinations with Requires, After, PartOf, and BindsTo. I cant seem to find the right combination to make this work. The closet I have is

```
#binary1.service 
[Unit] 
BindsTo=binary2.timer
```

Which will start and stop binary2.timer is binary1.service is started or stopped. However If bianry2.timer is started or stopped, this will effect the service of binary1.service.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. It certainly sounds like a very unusual scenario. Can you give any more context about what these services and timers are, and why they should interact (or not interact) in this strange way?

Comment: We want to be able to start and stop binary1.service and binary2.timer when starting and stopping binary1.service.

- binary1.service, works as a watchdog service.

- binary2.service, is a service that cleans up files that are created.

- binary2.timer, is a timer that runs the binary2.service.


Is this unusual?

Comment: Do you really need a second service at all? Would it be sufficient to run your cleanups using `ExecStopPost=`?

Comment: Are you suggesting something like ```ExecStopPost=systemctl stop binary2.timer```?
Then remove the "BindsTo" entry?

After more testing, I scrapped using "BindsTo" and adjusted the binary2.timer to use 

```Requires=binary1.service After=binary1.service```

Now when I restart binary1.service it starts both, and when I stop binary1.service it stops both. Would be nice to be able to use "start" to start both.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you run the actual commands that need to be run to do the cleanup.

Comment: By "Clean up" you are referring to systemd clean up of services that I am trying to achieve (Start and stop the binaries that systemd is trying to start and stop)?

Comment: Since you still haven't actually said what these services do in enough detail, I'm not sure I can really help much more. "Clean up" was _your_ description of what the program run by binary2.service does.